Perfmon installation cannot find local hdf5 installation
I am currently trying to setup reframe on my laptop for a benchmark test of a data pipeline and I am using WSL with Debian (Ubuntu 20.04). I am currently using anaconda to build the reframe by sourcing a shell script from the test's repository. However I am getting the following error:
$ source share/setup-env.sh
Installing perfmon
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-install-phfd_0b_/tables_413d77d5966e4b208f97426d53756666/setup.py:18: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        import pkg_resources
      /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      * Using Python 3.11.7 (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:12:31) [GCC 11.2.0]
      * USE_PKGCONFIG: True
      .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
         You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
         library can be found by setting the ``HDF5_DIR`` environment
         variable or by using the ``--hdf5`` command-line option.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I am currently new to WSL and I am not entirely sure how to proceed from here. I tried installing the package using pip and conda (both locally and globally) but I haven't gotten any results. Any help would be appreciated!
